# JavaScript onclick event handler

Tags: javascript, event-handling

My work puts out a weekly newsletter.  There is a webpage where we link to all of the previous newsletters that we've done.  We use Mailchimp for the newsletter so when someone clicks to view the newsletter, they are sent to the document at Mailchimp's website.  We decided we don't want people to navigate all the way away from our website when they view the newsletter.  I used a JavaScript event handler for the most recent newsletter to make it open in a new window.  It works as expected.  The problem is that the way I did it, I think I would need a different function for each of the previous URLs, and for every subsequent URL.  Is there a single piece of script that would apply to all of the weblinks in the webpage, and make them open in a new window?

```
<a onclick="myFunction()"><span style="font-size:16px;"><u>E-News March 2nd</u></span></a> 
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      window.open("https://mailchimp.com/");
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Use a function parameter, and then have the function substitute the parameter into the URL.

Comment: There's no need for the function. You can just use `<a href="https://mailchimp.com" target="_blank">` to follow the link in a new window. You can just change the URL in each link.